# jboss 7, how to set thread pool size for http connector

Tags: multithreading, threadpool, jboss7.x

In jboss7, how to set the thread pool size for the http and https connectors. I am using standalone.xml for setting changes. Can anyone help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4):

You can add the max-connections attribute in standalone.xml like this:

[connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http" **max-connections="1000"**/]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-application-server/341-jboss-as-7-performance-tuning.html?start=3

Comment: Please avoid giving link only answers.If the link breaks, your answer will no longer be helpful. Plus, without any text, it is unlikely to come up in searches.

Answer (score 0):

Define new thread factory and thread pool executor in your standalone xml. Refer to following site for more details:
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.3/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/sect-Connector_Configuration.html

I had similar issue, Refer to my [SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35268924/java-waiting-connection-threads-created-by-http-connection-are-alive-for-very-l).

Answer (score 0):

You can configure it like this using `maxThreads` parameter:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false" >

<connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http" maxThreads="300" />
```

API documentation from jBoss site:

> maxThread:(int) The max number of active threads in this pool, default is 200