# Java: Waiting connection threads created by HTTP connection are alive for very long duration

Tags: java, soap, httpconnection, java-threads

I have a server side code which checks if SOAP service is up. Code looks like:

```
String response = "";

while (response.length() == 0) {
    try {
        final URL url = new URL("DummySoapServiceURL");
        final HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");

            inputStream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
            final byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            while (inputStream.read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE) != -1) {
                response = new String(buffer);
            }
        } finally {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(inputStream);
            httpConnection.disconnect();
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // error handling
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // error handling
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that, for every check around 3-4 connection threads are created. And these threads are alive even if SOAP service check is completed. Snapshot of thread dump, for these threads looks like:

```
"http-host/ip:port-11" prio=10 tid=0x00000000064f0000 nid=0x32cc waiting on condition [0x00002b54bc604000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000d5093c78> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$DefaultThreadFactory$1$1.run(NioEndpoint.java:1249)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None
```

Now I am not sure why these connections threads are waiting/parking and how to close them. In my code opened streams are closed and connections is disconnected using disconnect().

I also tried to set following HTTP property:

```
httpConnection.addRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
```

But it didn't help. I doubt that at some time JAVA might be closing these threads. But I don't know, when and how? JDK version is jdk1.7.0_51_x64. Please let me know, how can I stop these connection thread numbers from building up?

Comment: You did not describe your environment properly by just saying "In my code i have..". Is that code running on server side? Because if, then probably those threads named like "http-host/ip:port-11" have nothing to do with "your code" being the client but those are the standard threads of your webserver, waiting for incoming requests.

Comment: I just edited my question. Yes its server side code. I did debug and found that these threads are created right after input stream is fetched from HTTP connection, response is read from input stream. So I am sure that these waiting threads are created by code above.

Comment: When i run that code in a main-method, i do not have any other threads than main (and the jvm standard threads). By the name of the thread, the stack elements and your described environment i am 99.9 percent sure, that those threads are just managed by your server side host architecture.

Comment: And by the way: You  are not concatenating to response, but always overwriting it (when BUFFER_SIZE < total size)

Comment: Yes infact, I don't need that response. This is just initial check to make sure that SOAP service is up. I ignore that response. This code is deployed on JBOSS server (stateless session bean is making call to SOAP services). I am not sure how that would create a issue. Any idea?

Comment: What happens if you send requests to your JBoss, that do not use an http connection? What if you break your execution while inside those request handlers? What kind of threads do you see then?

Comment: I am already sending other requests to my JBOSS (e.g. MQ). No issues observed. What do you mean by breaking execution inside request handlers?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102909/discussion-between-realsim-and-user613114).

Comment: @realsim: Sent this message in chat window but not sure if you rcvd it- Many thanks for your time and your valuable guidance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migrated whole implementation to use apache HTTP client as it has special APIs for better control. But it didn't help. Even with apache HTTP client, I could see these waiting connection threads.

Finally found hint on [redhat website for JBOSS HTTP connector configuration](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.3/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/sect-Connector_Configuration.html). Configured thread pool for HTTP connector and it solved the issue:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:threads:1.1"> 
    <thread-factory name="http-connector-factory" group-name="uq-thread-pool" thread-name-pattern="HTTP-%t" priority="9"/> 
    <unbounded-queue-thread-pool name="uq-thread-pool"> 
        <max-threads count="5"/> 
        <keepalive-time time="5" unit="seconds"/> 
        <thread-factory name="http-connector-factory"/> 
    </unbounded-queue-thread-pool> 
</subsystem> 

<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:2.2" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">

    <connector name="http" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" scheme="http" socket-binding="http" executor="uq-thread-pool"/> 
    ....
    ....
```